# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am following one tutorial that is obviously done in rails 3 and I am using rails 4. I get this error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

With this code:

```
def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
end
```

Obviously it has something with strong param

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all attributes required to create a `Movie` are whitelisted.

Define a method like this in your controller:

```
private
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :rating, :release_date)
end
```

And then pass the result of the method into `create!`:

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.create!(movie_params)
  # ...
end
```

[Read more about strong parameters in the Rails documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do that but now I get this error: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)

Comment: That's not saying a lot. Can you post the line of code where the error is happening?

Comment: Agian same line of code just now it looks like this:              @movie = Movie.create!(:title,:rating,:release_date)